# Where are User-level Xcode breakpoints saved?

Tags: xcode

I'm using User-level breakpoints in Xcode (i.e., breakpoints that are shared across projects – right-click on breakpoint > "Move Breakpoints To" > "User").

I see that breakpoints specific to a project are saved in $project.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/$username.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist, but User-level breakpoints do not appear in this file.

Anyone have any idea where User-level breakpoints are saved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The User level breakpoints you define in Xcode (at least in 7.0.1) are stored in

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
```

Which is a simple XML file.

Comment: @nSquid It is not. The question asked for **user level** (ie. shared across projects) breakpoints, not *project specific* breakpoints, which the answer by accfews is about (and it was already mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 1):

For the latest versions of Xcode (checked with 13.4)

If you work on a project with workspace:

```
%PROJECT%.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/%USERNAME%.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
```

If you don't have a workspace:

```
%PROJECT%.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/%USERNAME%.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
```

Just replace `PROJECT` and `USERNAME` with yours.